# How do i load data set part of the MASS library in R?

Tags: r

I am working through this book dealing with statistical learning/machine learning and R. One of the problem states:

> To begin, load in the Boston data set. The Boston data set is part of
>   the MASS library in R.

```
library (MASS)
```

> Now the data set is contained in the object `Boston`.
>
> Read about the data set:

`?Boston`

I don't understand the syntax `library(MASS)`. How do I get the Boston data set from this? I've tried `Boston=library(MASS)` but that gives me an array of words:

```
"MASS" "stats"  "graphics"  "grDevices" "utils" "datasets" "methods"   "base"
```

I've also tried something like `Boston=library(MASS::Boston)` but that doesn't seem to be valid either.

Comment: That only gives me [1] Boston when i display the object Boston from doing Boston=data(Boston).

EDIT: fixed with the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to assign the data to a new object also called `Boston`, `data()` loads the object `Boston` into the global environment:

```
> library(MASS)
> data(Boston)
> head(Boston)
     crim zn indus chas   nox    rm  age    dis rad tax ptratio  black lstat
1 0.00632 18  2.31    0 0.538 6.575 65.2 4.0900   1 296    15.3 396.90  4.98
2 0.02731  0  7.07    0 0.469 6.421 78.9 4.9671   2 242    17.8 396.90  9.14
3 0.02729  0  7.07    0 0.469 7.185 61.1 4.9671   2 242    17.8 392.83  4.03
4 0.03237  0  2.18    0 0.458 6.998 45.8 6.0622   3 222    18.7 394.63  2.94
5 0.06905  0  2.18    0 0.458 7.147 54.2 6.0622   3 222    18.7 396.90  5.33
6 0.02985  0  2.18    0 0.458 6.430 58.7 6.0622   3 222    18.7 394.12  5.21
  medv
1 24.0
2 21.6
3 34.7
4 33.4
5 36.2
6 28.7
>
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`library`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/library.html) function will loads a package in your workspace, in this case of:

```
library (MASS)
```

this will be the [MASS](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MASS/MASS.pdf) package. This package already contains the `Boston` data-frame which can be accessed immediately.